# Is it possible to recover tabs on Safari 16?

Tags: safari, monterey

Needing some help and advice.

Running Safari 16 on Monterey 12.6.

Is it possible to recover tabs anymore? I used to be able to do this using lastsession.plist. That doesn't work anymore. Also, open last session failed.

I am able to recover some from the lastsession.plist file using an editor and some manual copy pasting but I cant recover all the sessions.

Also, how can I make backup copies of my last session information? I am not sure what files I need to save.

Answer (score 1):

The History menu should contain everywhere you went in the past week, unless you cleared it.
Show All History gives you a searchable list of everywhere you've ever been since you last cleared history.
Recently closed should save perhaps the last 20 or so.
Reopen Last Tab [Window] will restore the Recently Closed list in reverse order.
Reopen All Windows From Last Session should restore your entire working state.

[image]

None of this information is saved for Private Browsing pages.

Comment: Unfortunately, history doesnt contain the pages I had open. History has never been cleared. Also, history contains pages open on other devices which makes it even more confusing. There is no way to recover sessions that were open. Also, there is no way to back up session data.

Comment: Not sure what to suggest. I've never known it fail. I have History going back years [since I once accidentally cleared it 6 or 7 years ago] on El Cap, Mojave & Monterey - they even migrate nicely when we ship in a new Mac.

Comment: This really would all be alleviated by being able to use lastsession.plist but since apple foolishly deprecated that and really anyway to recover session files, looks like all is lost.

Comment: see https://www.reddit.com/r/Safari/comments/pvcz1v/safari_15_and_lastsessionplist/ and https://github.com/ydkhatri/mac_apt/issues/78 I can't help otherwise as I've never had it fail.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to restore an older version from TimeMachine, the folder you have to restore is

/Users//Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Safari

If you do not want to restore it completely, the file name is SafariTabs.db

Comment: Thanks, a few questions (1) what do you mean by restore and restore completely? (2) Also, if my session is completely lost and the "restore last session" doesn't work, do I need to copy SafariTabs.db or the whole folder?  (3) can I do this manually through a cron job? I don't have TM

Comment: I lost my open tabs and then I went into TM to restore that folder and got them back; nothing else was changed (bookmarks etc). You don't need it from a TM backup but through some backup, hope that helps.

Comment: what you mean by restore it completely? you referring to the session?

Comment: I did it for the session tabs

Comment: Ok, so you copy and paste all the items in the backup to /Users//Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Safari then click "restore last session" and all your sessions will come back?